# Redirect static CMS pages

Tags: php, url, magento, redirect

I have a page called "category" which is located at `/category`. This page also has a bunch of variables in the querystring, such as `/category?id=4&page=1`. How can I use Magento's URL rewrites to make the URL look like `/category/4/1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have url rewriting (pretty urls) enabled, you could simply use the url `/category/id/4/page/1`. You'd get these values through the request object, from within your controller: `$this->getRequest()->get('id')`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It gives a 404. The category page is a custom page, not the standard category page.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion:

If you want an even more SEO friendly URL I would suggest creating a URL rewrite in Magento after you have improved your controller with the code posted by Vague. We use these a every now and then.

```
Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management -> Add URL Rewrite
```

request path: your_custom_page_name.html

id path: `/category/id/4/page/1`

target path: `/category/id/4/page/1`

Comment: the ID could be anything and the page number could also be anything.